# HTML placeholder does not work for Android

Tags: css, html, placeholder

I have a mobile version of my site and on the login page I use "placeholder" to display: Email or Password (instead of using label).

For iPhone it's working but not for Android, it disabled my field css (borders, colors etc...)

**Edit:**
I want to be able to use iPhone OS3, OS4 and Android 1 and 2

Why ?

Comment: which phone model ? what version of android ?

Comment: My guess is that older versions of chrome for android didn't support the placeholder attribute. It should however not change the way the css is applied. You could use a little bit of javascript the accomplish the same effect in browsers that don't support the placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it!

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

[How to get rid of placeholder on password field taken over from label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828263/how-to-get-rid-of-placeholder-on-password-field-taken-over-from-label)